# How Do I Completely Remove collection-fs from Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to remove all collection-fs completely. I manually remove them from versions, but when I run meteor, it throws them all back in again:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           

Changes to your project's package version selections:

cfs:access-point        added, version 0.1.49 
cfs:base-package        added, version 0.0.30
cfs:collection          added, version 0.5.5
cfs:collection-filters  added, version 0.2.4
cfs:data-man            added, version 0.0.6
cfs:file                added, version 0.1.17
cfs:gridfs              added, version 0.0.33
cfs:http-methods        added, version 0.0.32
cfs:http-publish        added, version 0.0.13
cfs:power-queue         added, version 0.9.11
cfs:reactive-list       added, version 0.0.9
cfs:reactive-property   added, version 0.0.4
cfs:s3                  added, version 0.1.3
cfs:standard-packages   added, version 0.5.9
cfs:storage-adapter     added, version 0.2.3
cfs:tempstore           added, version 0.1.5
cfs:upload-http         added, version 0.0.20
cfs:worker              added, version 0.1.4
```

Is there a better way to get rid of collection-fs completely. It is preventing me from updating to Meteor 1.4.1.1. Specifically `cfs:gridfs`.

I tried meteor `remove cfs:gridfs`but got `cfs:gridfs is not a direct dependency in this project.`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Removing entries from versions won't remove packages.
Another package has a dependency on collection-fs, and you'll need to work that out to solve this.

Comment: Well Mike, you solved it. As I was telling perusopersonale down there, I was working on a project with Coursera. They gave us an assignment using ryw:blog from atmosphere. That's what was throwing all the cfs versions which are deprecated and gave me that error. I deleted the ryw:blog package and all those versions disappeared and my build is error free!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove from all cfs packages from .meteor/packages file not from versions.

Comment: That's the problem. I have no cfs packages! I downloaded a starter app from Coursera and it was just like that - no cfs packages but a bunch of cfs versions. Now, even if I create a brand new fresh app, those cfs versions show up in it as well.